# ¿Cómo enviar múltiples post en una función de Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

Estoy aprendiendo Javascript y tengo una duda, no consigo que se me envien dos posts en una función. En el siguiente ejemplo se puede ver mejor:

```
function(start, end, label) {
                    $.post('/endpoint1', {
                        start_date_db: JSON.stringify(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
                        end_date_db: JSON.stringify(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))


                    }, 

                    $.post('/endpoin2', {
                        start_date_db: JSON.stringify(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
                        end_date_db: JSON.stringify(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))

                    }
```

Cuando ejecuto el código, sólo llama el primer post (endpoint). He probado de repetir la función y llamar por seperado a los endpoints, pero al parecer tampoco a funcionado.

Gracias, cualquier aportación será bienvenida :D

Comment: No hace el request?

Comment: `endpoin2` sin `t`, ¿estás seguro que está bien escrito?

Comment: Ya está solucionado, adjunto respuesta. Era cosa que cerraba mal los paréntesis de la petición post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas llamar dos funciones por separado:

```
function(start, end, label) {
  $.post('/endpoint1', {
    start_date_db: JSON.stringify(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
    end_date_db: JSON.stringify(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
  }, function(data) {
    console.log('primer resultado', data);
  });

  $.post('/endpoin2', {
    start_date_db: JSON.stringify(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')),
    end_date_db: JSON.stringify(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
  }, function(data) {
    console.log('segunda resultado', data);
  });
```

Tenga en cuenta que $ .post toma tres argumentos: endpoint, data y la función a la que se llamará cuando los datos regresen del servidor.

P.S JSON.stringify e extra. Puedes usar:

```
start_date_db: start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Era justamente eso, gracias. Al no poner los paréntesis bien de la primera petición, no me cogía la segunda.